# Open a jQueryUI Dialog After Database Information Populates Controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax

I am playing around with C# and the jQuery UI Dialog box tonight. I have added a dialog div to a user management page that will enable Administrators to edit user information (such as address, phone, aspnetdb stuff). When the admin clicks on a row in a grid view, the dialog is activated, but the controls (text boxes and drop downs) take a few seconds to populate with the information. I would like the dialog to present the user's information, allow changes to the controls, allow the administrator to save the data, and then update the grid view which is inside of an update panel.

Is there a way through Code Behind and jQuery to only show the dialog box after all of the fields have been filled in by the Datatable (dataset xsd)?

Thanks in advance for your help. This has stumped me for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the following scenario:

1. When a user clicks on a grid row, an ajax request will be made through [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that gets the appropriate data based on the user's selection.
2. the `jquery.ajax` function has an `onSuccess` callback function which activates the jqueryUI dialog.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myUrl.aspx/MethodName",
  type: "POST",
  data: ({id : my_grid_selected_id}),
  success: function(result){
   // Do the dialog fields population here.
   $( "#myDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  }
}
);
```

UPDATE: Here's how you can populate data in you dialog's controls. I'll try to explain it with an example.

Server-Side (Method **has to be static and has a `[WebMethod()]` attribute**).

```
public class CustomData
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
}

[WebMethod()]
public static CustomData ReturnCustomData(int MyID)
{
    CustomData MyData = new CustomData();
    MyData.name = "Custom name";
    MyData.id = MyID;
    return MyData;
}
```

Client-Side:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myUrl.aspx/ReturnCustomData",
  type: "POST",
  data: ({MyID : my_grid_selected_id}),
  success: function(result){
  $("your_name_textbox_identifier").val(result.name);
  $("your_id_textbox_identifier").val(result.id);
  $( "#myDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  }
});
```

For populating dropdown lists, check out http://www.isolutionteam.co.uk/how-to-populate-aspnet-dropdown-list-from-database-by-passing-radio-button-lists-selected-value-as-parameter-with-jquery/

Comment: With the code you specified above...would the url: "myUrl.aspx" be the page I want loaded in the dialog? If that is the case, this would be exactly what I am looking for as I need a way to send the userid to the edit user page via post.

Comment: Updated the answer to be more precise. The MethodName is the method that retrieves the data for the selected row from database. you can see an exmaple at http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I almost follow...Now if I want to fill textbox/drop down controls with address, city, state, zip, etc. would i need to create a method that returns all of the values? Also, on success, would I load UserFunctions.aspx and fill the controls [$('#addUser').load('UserFunctions.aspx' + ' #AddUser, function()...]? If that is the case, how do you populate the controls?

Comment: For populating the controls, you should return all the data just as usual. then you have access to the db-retrieved data in `result` or `result.d` based on the browser. I'll update the answer in a bit...

Comment: Oh Kamyar...that is exactly what I am looking for. Did not even know you could do that. That opens up so many possibilities that my mind has just gone into overdrive. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @ThaKidd: Very happy I could help you. also, take a look at rick strahl's excellent blog post: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx It has so much informative stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can just brute force this:  say one of your fields looks like:

```
<input id='some_field'>
```

You can test to see if it's been populated with:

```
    if ($("#some_field").val() !== "")
```

And you can repeatedly check with a timer:

```
var fieldLoaded = setInterval( function() {
    if ($("#some_field").val() !== "") {
      clearInterval(fieldLoaded);
      $("#my_dialog").show();  
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: I like your idea as a guarantee that something did occur.